# Trouble creating SQL table dynamically from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        AddNewRowToGrid();
}
```

My ASPX code is:

```
 <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                   <asp:Button ID="btn_add_column" runat="server" Text="Click Here to Add column" 
                        onclick="btn_add_column_Click" />
<%--                         <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click"/>
--%>                </td>
            </tr>

 <asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     <%-- <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>--%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data Type">
            <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddldatatype" runat="server">
                  <asp:ListItem>varchar</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>int</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>numeric</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>uniqueidentifier</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>char</asp:ListItem>
                  </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click"/>
             <asp:Button ID="ButtonDel" runat="server" Text="Delete Row" OnClick="ButtonDel_Click"/>
             <input type="hidden" runat="server" value="0" id="hiddencount" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Now I want to delete textbox onclick of Delete Row

I tried this on ButtonDel_Click

```
 private void DeleteNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count-1; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    //TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("ddldatatype");

                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i+ 1;
                    drCurrentRow["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                    //drCurrentRow["Column3"] = box3.Text;

                    rowIndex--;
                }
                //add new row to DataTable
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                //Store the current data to ViewState
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                //Rebind the Grid with the current data
                Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
       // SetPreviousData();
    }
    protected void ButtonDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DeleteNewRowToGrid();
    }
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the
>   size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

What could be the problem?

Comment: Someone will be along to close this pretty quickly unless you ask a question.

Comment: What are you asking? What do you want us to do with that code? Are there errors you get? Something you fail to accomplish?

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating sql table dynamically from c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213471/creating-sql-table-dynamically-from-c)

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all, the index was out of range...
Probably somewhere in your for loop you call an index that does not exist.

Moreover you can optimize your for loop a bit:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
...
rowIndex--;
```

I think your rowIndex is the cause of the error. First you assign it to 0 then you try rowindex = 0 - 1. Which becomes -1.
If you use -1 as an index value it collapses.

EDIT:
This implies that you should change `rowIndex --;` to `rowIndex ++;` or change int `rowIndex = 0;` to another higher number.

SECOND AND THIRD EDIT:

You can do this instead:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //extract the TextBox values
            TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
            //TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
            DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("ddldatatype");

            drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
            drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i;
            drCurrentRow["Column1"] = box1.Text;
            drCurrentRow["Column2"] = box2.Text;
            //drCurrentRow["Column3"] = box3.Text;
            //add new row to DataTable
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
        }
```

I hope it helps you a step further.

Comment: this is my code to add textbox dynamically

Comment: Did you changed the initial rowIndex value or did you set rowIndex-- to rowIndex++?

Comment: now it's giv ing me erro like "The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection. "

Comment: @user913947 It is still not very clear to me what you try to accomplish. But try my last edit...

Comment: u tell me that how shold I explain code...

Comment: @Mixxiphoid - I believe the OP is trying to delete a row from the GridView and the underlying DataTable - and going about it the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has

```
rowIndex--;
```

instead of

```
rowIndex++;
```